# Select qty of minimum customerID

Tags: sql-server

```
Product_Code  Month  Qty  Area  CustomerID
------------  -----  ---  ----  ----------
820300182     01     1    M1    100078
820300182     01     50   M1    100168
820300182     01     20   M1    100188
820300182     01     10   M1    100618
820300182     01     10   M1    100938
820300182     01     20   M1    100988
820300182     01     25   M1    110158
```

I want to get `Qty` of minimum `customerID`.

E.g.,

```
Product_Code  Month  Qty  Area  CustomerID
------------  -----  ---  ----  ----------
820300182     01     1    M1    100078
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Please note that you can **edit** your question if you want to improve it or add additional information. Do not post a new question instead - it will just end up closed and deleted and eventually it might result in an automated question ban for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you want to find the record with the lowest CustomerId:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [Product_Code], [Month], [Qty], [Area], [CustomerID]
FROM [TABLE]
ORDER BY [CustomerId] ASC
```

If you however need to find the record with the least quantity then change the order by to

```
ORDER BY [Qty] ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
Select Qty
from tableName
where CustomerID = ( select min(CustomerID) from tableName )
```